# How to fetch parameters when using the Apache Commons CLI library

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-cli

I'm using the Apache Commons CLI to handle command line arguments in Java.

I've declared the `a` and `b` options and I'm able to access the value using `CommandLine.getOptionValue()`.

```
Usage: myapp [OPTION] [DIRECTORY]

Options:
-a        Option A
-b        Option B
```

How do I declare and access the DIRECTORY variable?

Comment: How did you make the `HelpFormatter` print `[OPTION] [DIRECTORY]`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the following method:

```
CommandLine.getArgList()
```

which returns whatever's left after options have been processed.

Comment: what if the number of argument for all options is unlimited?

Answer (score 7):

It may be better to use another Option (-d) to identify directory which is more intuitive to the user.

Or the following code demonstrates getting the remaining argument list

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final CommandLineParser parser = new BasicParser();
    final Options options = new Options();
    options.addOption("a", "opta", true, "Option A");
    options.addOption("b", "optb", true, "Option B");

    final CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);

    final String optionA = getOption('a', commandLine);
    final String optionB = getOption('b', commandLine);

    final String[] remainingArguments = commandLine.getArgs();

    System.out.println(String.format("OptionA: %s, OptionB: %s", optionA, optionB));
    System.out.println("Remaining arguments: " + Arrays.toString(remainingArguments));
}

public static String getOption(final char option, final CommandLine commandLine) {

    if (commandLine.hasOption(option)) {
        return commandLine.getOptionValue(option);
    }

    return StringUtils.EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: To that, I'd add that the HelpFormatter would be used to print the [DIRECTORY] argument:

`HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();`
`formatter.printHelp("myapp [OPTION] [DIRECTORY]", options);`